# for each product list all branches

Tags: sql

I have a list of products in table and a list of branches as below

T_product

| Code | Desc |
| --- | --- |
| product1 | Banana |
| product2 | Apple |

T_branch

| Code | Branch |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Branch 1 |
| 02 | Branch 2 |

I need to to create a a table to to joins each product with all branches

| ProdCode | branchCode |
| --- | --- |
| product1 | Branch 1 |
| Product1 | Branch 2 |
| product2 | Branch 1 |
| Product2 | Branch 2 |

etc

I haven't really tried much, I've bene googling but haven't found the answer I need, as I don't really know what to look for. Any guidance on terminology would be great so I know. If it was programing it would be a simple nested loop.

I need to create this list to join other tables too, but as the other data only

Comment: Looks like a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, got carried away i have amended the original request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a cartesian product or cross-join.  You actually don't need to do anything to make this happen; just listing the tables in your from clause with no where clause will do it.  It's typically considered an error, but as your example shows, sometimes you need it.  You can combine this with other, properly joined tables by putting only the relevant conditions in the WHERE clause and just not specifying any constraints against those two tables.

See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm

Comment: The recommended syntax is `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Sure, but it should be understood that this is essentially the same as a comment, which is handy for future maintainers in letting them know you did this intentionally.  I don't know of any RDMSs that mandate you using CROSS JOIN, but I'd be curious to find out if there are.

Comment: The comma separated, implicit join syntax is still valid ANSI SQL. But that doesn't make it a good idea to teach new users to use it.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `CROSS JOIN` :

```
select p.Code as ProdCode, b.Branch as branchCode
from T_product p
cross join T_branch b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CROSS JOIN to join each row of one table to each row of the second table:

```sql
select p.Code as ProdCode, b.Branch as branchCode
from T_product as p
cross join T_branch as b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use even a simple Descartes-multiplication, like

```
select T_product.Code as ProdCode, T_branch as branchCode
from T_product, T_branch
```